# qooxdoo : add a toolbar to Grid layout?

Tags: qooxdoo

How to add a toolbar to Grid layout ?

```
var container = new qx.ui.container.Composite();
var layout = new qx.ui.layout.Grid(2,2);
container.setLayout(layout);
var w1 = new qx.ui.core.Widget();

var toolbar = new qx.ui.toolbar.ToolBar();
var btn_status = new qx.ui.toolbar.Button("I am a button");
toolbar.add(btn_status);

container.add(w1, {row: 0, column: 0});
// w1.add(toolbar); // <----
container.set({backgroundColor : "white"});
this.getRoot().add(container, {edge: 0});
```

If I uncomment the only commented line, the layout will be blank, no error prompted.

What did I miss ? I'm working on `qx.Desktop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not need for the intermediate widget (`var w1 = new qx.ui.core.Widget();`). Actually `qx.ui.core.Widget` is not a container, it has no `add()` method. There's probably an error shown on the Javascript console.

You can add the toolbar directly to the composite.

```
container.add(toolbar, {row: 0, column: 0});
```

Comment: thanks! saved my life! then what does `qx.ui.core.Widget` use for, apart from setting its background color ?

Comment: You're welcome :)
In general it's used as abstract class for all qooxdoo's widget.
As it does nothing but render a square it is sometimes used to paint a  color but I'm not sure if it's a good idea.